# Incorrect uialertiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

I have code that shows a uialertview with a long message:

```
alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"looong text" message:@"text to loong" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField *myTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
myTextField.delegate = self;
[alert show];   
alert.frame = CGRectMake(
    alert.frame.origin.x,
    alert.frame.origin.y - 50,
    alert.frame.size.width, 
    300);
```

But I get:

[image: this instead]

Comment: The code you provided doesn't seem to line up with the screen shot. Also, please clarify the problem that you're having

Comment: wrong text of message

Comment: Make the text more concise and don't set the frame explicitly. If what you want won't fit, create a custom view controller and present it...

Answer (score 4):

You should not mess with the [`UIAlertView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) it is even in the docs.

> **Subclassing Notes**
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is
>   and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is
>   private and must not be modified.

Better option it to create your own view and display that.

Comment: I cannot see that UIAlertView is subclassed here, or the view hierarchy modified. What am I overlooking?

Comment: You care changing the size and that will also not work. You can not change anything of design/presentation of the UIAlertView.

Answer (score 0):

I added this code to my class. And it work good for me

```
-(void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    if(alertView.tag == ZIP_CODE_TAG){
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] <7)
    {
        NSArray *subviewArray = [alertView subviews];
        UILabel *message = (UILabel *)[subviewArray objectAtIndex:2];
        message.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        message.numberOfLines = 0;
        [message setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 95, 260, 100)];

        UIButton *okbutton = (UIButton *)[subviewArray objectAtIndex:3];
        [okbutton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 240, 260, 42)];

        UIButton *cancelbutton = (UIButton *)[subviewArray objectAtIndex:4];
        [cancelbutton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 287, 260, 42)];

        UITextField *textfield = (UITextField *)[subviewArray objectAtIndex:5];
        [textfield setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 198, 260, 50)];

        UITextField *placeTF = (UITextField *)[subviewArray objectAtIndex:6];
        [placeTF setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 188, 256, 50)];
    }
}
```

}